# Get a node and fields with SQL?

Tags: 7, entities, database

Is there any way in Drupal 7 to load a node and its fields without the Entity Query API?  I need to get a field value based on another field in an external script, and don't want to bootstrap Drupal.

Comment: In my opinion this question is off-topic and not about Drupal -- if you don't want to boostrap and use Drupal's API. Simply put -- anything is possible if you know `SQL`, joins, temporary tables etc. But there are many reasons why it's simply a bad idea.

Comment: Don't want to bootstrap drupal or don't want to run entity load hooks?

Comment: This is not off-topic, and IS about Drupal, because it pertains to the Drupal schema and how the Entity system stores data in the database.

I know SQL just fine, but I can't seem to figure out the correct tables for linking up the field tables to the node tables.  Where are entities stored?